# Firebase Phone Authentication - Internalization of verification SMS text

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In firebase auth documentation it is mentioned that we can internationalize the authentication sms language with the following call. For instance to

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setLanguageCode("fr");
```

should set the message language to french.

Actually on android I never got this to work sms are arriving on the template language set on firebase console

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To change the language in the template for the following:

> SMS verification
>
> Password Reset
>
> Email address Change

Do the following:

1. Go to firebase console
2. click on authentication
3. Click on templates

Inside the templates you have this:

[image: Change language]

You can then change the language by clicking on the edit button next to Template language English.

Comment: Yes, as I commented the sms is arriving on this language, without taking into consideration the app language. The thing is that we would like to send the SMS depending on the app language. I.e.: sometimes english, sometimes spanish, etc...

Comment: the template language can be changed in the template only, so if you change it from english to spanish here you will get it as spanish . I see now which langauge did you try and add in the `setLanguagecode`?

Comment: I tried various. Spanish, French. I tried: "SP", "ES", "FR", "fr", "ES-es" non of this was working.

Comment: try `auth.useAppLanguage()`

Comment: can you please write the full code where you are using it? @Yunnyyy

Comment: @Yunnyyy dont add that line inside `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` please add it outside so it will work

Comment: I just added to Application onCreate function and tried with both useAppLanguage and setLanguageCode. The sms sent is still in the template's language.

Comment: did u authenticate the user before using it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Android version that supports client side localization. Also, are you using your own custom templates? If so, Firebase Auth does not localize custom email templates.